# Ошибка в кодировке

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Помогите устранить следущую ошибку. Я создал базу данных, в бд создал таблицу. В таблице создал 2 столбца с русским текстом. При выполнении запроса из этой таблице на сайте пишутся иероглифы за место русского текста,а цифры и англ буквы нормально выводятся. Эти 2 столбца имеют тип VARCHAR и TEXT, а их кодировка utf8_general_ci. Как избавиться от этой ошибки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) для Apache в **.htaccess**:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

2) для nginx в конфиге:

```
charset utf8;
```

3) в **html-документе**:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```

html 5 версия:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

4) необходимо все сущности (таблицы) установить в кодировку `utf8_general_ci`

5) если используете PDO:

```
new \PDO(
    'mysql:
    host=localhost;
    dbname=db;
    charset=utf8;',
    'user',
    'pass'
)
```

6) если всё ещё пользуетесь процедурным доступом к БД, то:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

7) в Вашем редакторе/IDE сохраняйте файл в кодировке `utf8`

Comment: Я пользуюсь процедурным способом,но все равно не помогает

Comment: Первый способ помог.Спасибо

Comment: я всегда пишу mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');  
Это очень плохо?

Comment: @Dazar Почитайте про PDO.

[Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных][1]

Кроме того, обратите внимание, что написано в красной рамочке:

[PHP: mysql_query - Manual][2]

Оф. релиз PHP 5.5 уже очень скоро;)

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/
  [2]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @Sergey4590 Возьми себе за правило использовать в проектах все эти три условия, а не по отдельности.

Comment: Ок.Только непонятно почему такая ошибка вылазила,я ведь кодировку точно в бд и в таблице ставил.

Comment: @romeo то есть уже смело пора переделывать и забрасывать далеко все mysql_query("UPDATE table SET...") в пользу PDO?

Comment: Вообще, странно что кто-то использует процедурные функции, когда существует классы (PDO, Date, Exception  и т.д.).  PHP потихоньку уходит от старого наследия в пользу нативного ООП.

PDO кроме того, позволяет эффективно бороться с sql-инъекциями применив плейсхолдеры в запросе.

Comment: @Sergey4590 И да,
4) В БД, как Вы уже отметили, нужно все сущности (таблицы) установить в кодировку utf8_general_ci.

С выходом PHP 5.5. выполнение данных пунктов, если не всех, то значительной её части не потребуется, ибо планируется поддержка unicode-кодировки по умолчанию.

Comment: @romeo Мне понравилось выражение "нативное ООП" (т.е. аборигентское ООП). Плюс.

Answer (score 2):

При подключении юзать:
     mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn);

Если не спасет попробовать:
     mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8', $conn);

Желательно также проверить, чтоб база данных целиком и таблица тоже были в utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Это уже все и бд точно в этой кодировке

Answer (score 0):

Иногда нужно чтобы помимо всего проделанного были и сами файлы в UTF8 Не просто прописать это в мета, но и сохранить их в этой кодировке, например через notepad++ и ему подобные. У меня когда похожие проблемы были, это решалось именно так.

Comment: У меня это часто помогало даже без применения в .htaccess: 
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
и причем не просто в UTF8, а в UTF8 без BOM, иначе из файлов .php (может быть еще каких-то) могут выводиться неожиданные символы